# Cleaning master branch to version from another branch, but save progress to new temp branch

Tags: git, branch

What is the best way to move all progress on the master branch from point X to a new temporary branch (e.g., new_master), rewind all changes to point X, and finally commit all changes from branch A as master.

This is what I have:
[image: existing_git]

And what I want to achieve is:

1. Move all changes from master, from "some changes" point to new branch.
2. Merge all changes from 1.0.1.120 branch to master (but I must preserve pom.xml files from master)

Comment: Judging by the answers and what you wrote, I think you should clarify a few things. when you say "move all changes from master, from some changes point to new branch". Do you mean that `new_branch` should contain all the changes **up to** `some changes` , or actually **from** `some changes`, and therefore having `new_branch` as an exact copy of the current `master` branch? Also, when you say "move", do you mean that those commits should appear only in `new_branch` and disappear from `master`, therefore resetting `master` to `some changes`?

Answer (score 0):

1. create your branch from commit hash (first commit message.)

   ```
    git checkout <sha1-of-commit (first commit message)>
    git checkout my-new-branch
   ```
2. do your changes on your new branch as usual

Step 3 has variations, depending on what is easier:

3.1) do merge of master to your new branch with --no-commit option.

- you will have all the files from master, and you can simply revert/remove changes that you don't want to have and then finally commit and merge back to master.

3.2) Save your pom files from master somewhere then merge master, without changes,e.g. keep your changes, and then manually add your saved pom files.:

```
git merge -s ours master # merge master but keep only my changes
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do the following:

**1. Move all changes from master, from "some changes" point to new branch**

```
git branch new_master <sha1-of-commit (some changes)>
```

**2. Merge all changes from 1.0.1.120 branch to master (but I must preserve pom.xml files from master)**

```
git merge 1.0.1.120
```

You must be on master branch for this second command, assuming 1.0.1.120 hasn't changed your pom.xml file. If so, then do a merge without commiting:

```
git merge --no-commit 1.0.1.120
```

Then get your master branch pom.xml

```
git checkout master pom.xml
```

And finally commit

```
git commit
```